# Upload image to Web using C# Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, php, xamarin.android, image-uploading

1. I want to upload my image using POST, but it always show an error while uploading the file ("There was an error uploading the file, please try again"). When I echo `$link`, only "uploaded//" appears.
2. How do I rename the "file" variable in `$_FILES["file"]` in my C# code?

variabel uriFotoAndr.Path return :

> /storage/sdcard1/DCIM/Camera/MYIMAGE.jpg

C# Code :

```
System.Net.WebClient Client = new System.Net.WebClient();
Client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");

byte[] result = Client.UploadFile("my.web.com/ppl/post_image.php", "POST", uriFotoAndr.Path);
string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);
Toast.MakeText(this, s, ToastLength.Long).Show();
```

PHP Code :

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = 'uploaded/'; 
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
 {
     $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
     $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
     $link= $uploads_dir."/".$name;
     if( move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $link))
     {
        echo "Success: Picture Upload Successfully!";
     }
     else
     {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!".$link;
     }
  }
  else
  {
     echo "Error: Picture not Uploaded";
  }
?>
```

I am using VS 2015 and Xamarin to build this app. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try seperating your code problems out - perhaps  try using Postman (https://www.getpostman.com) to debug your PHP code before calling it from android

Comment: thanks @Jmons for your response, i already use Insomnia, that's similar with postman and i can upload image files.

 I already found the answer, my web link on C# code is "http://mywebsite.com/post_image.php" then i add "www" => "http:/ /www.mywebsite.com/post_image.php and my code works! :D

Answer (score 1):

I already found the answer,

my web link on C# code before :

> http://mywebsite.com/post_image.php

then i add "www" to the link :

> http://www.mywebsite.com/post_image.php

and i can upload !!! :D